# GCE - We are unable to connect to the VM on port 22

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

I'm having the following error when I try to connect via SSH to my instance on Google Compute Engine.

```
Connection Failed. We are unable to connect to the VM on port 22.
```

**Steps I did to get that error**

- Created a new instance using an Ubuntu template.
- Connected via SSH and installed all my required apps.
- Deleted the instance but without deleting the boot disk when instance is deleted.
- Created a new custom image using the boot disk of the deleted instance.
- started a new instance using the custom image.
- Click on the SSH link from the GCE console.

This is the Serial console output for the instance.

```
[    0.338119] Loading compiled-in X.509 certificates
[    0.339445] Loaded X.509 cert 'Magrathea: Glacier signing key: e09b1e7e9841e9cfef256b70ab210562dab1ef68'
[    0.341236] registered taskstats version 1
[    0.342183] Key type trusted registered
[    0.342872] Key type encrypted registered
[    0.343453] AppArmor: AppArmor sha1 policy hashing enabled
[    0.344592] ima: No TPM chip found, activating TPM-bypass!
[    0.345433] evm: HMAC attrs: 0x1
[    0.345974]   Magic number: 0:206:635
[    0.346956] rtc_cmos 00:00: setting system clock to 2016-01-17 13:37:20 UTC (1453037840)
[    0.348137] BIOS EDD facility v0.16 2004-Jun-25, 0 devices found
[    0.349722] EDD information not available.
[    0.524305] input: AT Translated Set 2 keyboard as /devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input2
[    0.525744] md: Waiting for all devices to be available before autodetect
[    0.526718] md: If you don't use raid, use raid=noautodetect
[    0.527798] md: Autodetecting RAID arrays.
[    0.528396] md: Scanned 0 and added 0 devices.
[    0.529008] md: autorun ...
[    0.529414] md: ... autorun DONE.
[    0.529988] VFS: Cannot open root device "sda1" or unknown-block(0,0): error -6
[    0.530970] Please append a correct "root=" boot option; here are the available partitions:
[    0.532106] Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)
[    0.533250] CPU: 0 PID: 1 Comm: swapper/0 Not tainted 3.19.0-43-generic #49~14.04.1-Ubuntu
[    0.534451] Hardware name: Google Google, BIOS Google 01/01/2011
[    0.535409]  ffffea0002edc240 ffff88012af0fdb8 ffffffff817afcd5 00000000000011ba
[    0.536095]  ffffffff81a7c8b8 ffff88012af0fe38 ffffffff817a9b15 ffff88012af0fdd8
[    0.536095]  ffffffff00000010 ffff88012af0fe48 ffff88012af0fde8 ffff88012af0fe38
[    0.536095] Call Trace:
[    0.536095]  [<ffffffff817afcd5>] dump_stack+0x45/0x57
[    0.536095]  [<ffffffff817a9b15>] panic+0xc1/0x1f5
[    0.536095]  [<ffffffff81d3e5f3>] mount_block_root+0x210/0x2a9
[    0.536095]  [<ffffffff81d3e822>] mount_root+0x54/0x58
[    0.536095]  [<ffffffff81d3e993>] prepare_namespace+0x16d/0x1a6
[    0.536095]  [<ffffffff81d3e304>] kernel_init_freeable+0x1f6/0x20b
[    0.536095]  [<ffffffff81d3d9a7>] ? initcall_blacklist+0xc0/0xc0
[    0.536095]  [<ffffffff817a01d0>] ? rest_init+0x80/0x80
[    0.536095]  [<ffffffff817a01de>] kernel_init+0xe/0xf0
[    0.536095]  [<ffffffff817b7658>] ret_from_fork+0x58/0x90
[    0.536095]  [<ffffffff817a01d0>] ? rest_init+0x80/0x80
[    0.536095] Kernel Offset: 0x0 from 0xffffffff81000000 (relocation range: 0xffffffff80000000-0xffffffffbfffffff)
[    0.536095] ---[ end Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)
```

So my question is how can I connect via SSH to my instance and how to make sure it doesn't happen again when I create a new custom image.

Thanks.

Comment: are you sure your server is running? there seems to be issues with mounted disk: `Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)`

Comment: Did you modify the fstab file while installing your apps? if so, creating a brand new instance with the affected disk as secondary attached, you can check the logs and modify what is broken

Answer (score 18):

I had the same issue with one of my GCP VM instance. My solution was:

1. Shut down the instance
2. Click 'Edit' for the instance
3. Under 'Custom Metadata' section, add 'startup-script' key, with value:

```
#! /bin/bash
sudo ufw allow 22
```

4. Click 'Save'
5. Start the instance again, and SSH into it

Hope it helps!

Comment: Quang you're amazing.

Answer (score 1):

Restart your instance.It's work with me.

Answer (score 0):

opening google cloud - go to your VM Instance - click Stop - click start than its working well ...:)

This issue with SSH terminal  , because you directly close ssh terminal , you musch tyoe " " close " command than cancel the broswer's tab after you won't appear that issue :)

Good Luck .

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21196694)

Comment: Check my comment , in first line answered properly ok

Answer (score 0):

Please follow [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/using-tcp-forwarding#console):

1. create a new firewall rule and delete all existing firewall
2. stop the vm
3. restart your vm and try to run SSH

It will work.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is due to firewall setting.
If GCE Instance is created in default VPC , with default firewall it will deny all incoming traffic.
We need to explicitly create firewall rule which will allow traffic on port 22
Explained in detail in below video
**https://youtu.be/3HyEzL6fm-M**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).